# How to enable tracing in oracle reports Developer 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oraclereports, oracle-fusion-middleware

I am using oracle reports Developer 11g

[image]

but tracing is disables in it.

[image]

How can i enable tracing ?

Any hint will be great help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The trace option is *deliberately* disabled on `Reports Builder 11g`.

One cannot enable it as how it was done in earlier version (`10gR2` or `10g`). 
It won't be enabled by default as in `10g`.

`For Reports Builder` (`rwbuilder`) and `Reports Runtime` (`rwrun`) for `11g` (oracle calls version `10gR3` as `11g` ), specify tracing options in the `logging.xml` file manually as follows:

1. Stop Reports Builder if it's open.
2. It's strictly important to take a backup copy of the `%INSTANCE_HOME%\config\ReportsToolsComponent\ReportsTools\logging.xml` file. 
   Since these type of configuration files are not touched normally.

   In my case `%INSTANCE_HOME%` is `ORACLE_INSTANCE=C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1` 
   ( you may find this info in `default.env` file which may be found in      `C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\config\fmwconfig\servers\AdminServer\applications\formsapp_11.1.2\config` path as a standard example ).

   The produced logfiles are `C:\Oracle\Middleware\asinst_1\diagnostics\logs\ReportsToolsComponent\ReportsTools\runtime_diagnostic.log` and `zrclient_diagnostic.log` may be found in `value tag` of `path property` inside `logging.xml` file.
3. Open the `%INSTANCE_HOME%\config\ReportsToolsComponent\ReportsTools\logging.xml` file in a text editor.
4. Look for the section:

   ```
   <logger name='oracle.reports.runtime' level='NOTIFICATION:1' useParentHandlers='false'> 
   <handler name='runtime_trace_handler'/> 
   </logger>
   ```

Increase the level to the desired one.

The below table shows us the various Diagnostics logs that are available in this version (`11g`), its equivalent in the 10.1.2.0.2 Release and a brief explanation of the same :

[image]

5. Save the file and Restart `Reports Builder`.

Comment: I had made this changes before but this will not enable tracing button in report developer although i can see tracing log in log file. thanks

Comment: @p27 you're welcome. As i mentioned at the beginning, Oracle says that "The trace option is deliberately disabled on Reports Builder 11g".

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Barbaros Özhan, this only enable sql tracing, do you know how to trace all objects in the report ?

Comment: @p27 you're welcome friend. Unfortunately, i don't know.

Comment: @ Barbaros Özhan can you point me the document which says that this option is disabled in Report builder 11g

Comment: @p27 this document stated in support.oracle.com, if you have access, then you may search for `Doc ID 856664.1`

Comment: @p27 thank you, too. I wish you or any of your friend had an access to `oracle support`, and i'd like to hear about your progress. Have a nice day.